# NIC bonding mode 6 (balance-alb) only uses one NIC

Tags: 12.04, network-bonding

OS: Ubuntu 12.04LTS

`bonding` is in `/etc/modules` for automatic loading at boot

The bonding configuration works in `bond-mode 0` but not `bond-mode 6`

--

When the system boots `bond0` comes up with only `eth0` as slave

`eth1` is not up at all in ifconfig but can be brought up `ifconfig eth1 up`

However, even after it is brought up, it is not enslaved to `bond0`

Attempting to use `ifenslave bond0 eth1` results in `Master 'bond0', Slave 'eth1': Error: Enslave failed`

syslog reports that `bonding: bond0: Error: dev_set_mac_address of dev eth1 failed!`

However, I am able to use `ifconfig eth1 hw ether 123456789abc` to set the mac address on the adapter (works on both `eth0` and `eth1`)

```
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <mac address>
          inet addr:10.3.0.1  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:68ff:fe39:83c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9444 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2179485 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:1158406 (1.1 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:56:78:9a:bc:de     <-- set using ifconfig
          UP BROADCAST SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9444 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2179485 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:1158406 (1.1 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc    <-- set using ifconfig
          inet6 addr: fe80::1034:56ff:fe78:9abc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:1 frame:0
          TX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:689886 (689.8 KB)  TX bytes:28363 (28.3 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Base address:0xe800 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:76193 (76.1 KB)  TX bytes:76193 (76.1 KB)

lo:1      Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:172.16.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
```

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo lo:1 br0
iface lo inet loopback

auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
  endpoint 209.51.161.14
  address 2001:470:1f06:4ca::2
  gateway 2001:470:1f06:4ca::1
  netmask 64
  local 10.3.0.1
  up ip -6 route add default dev he-ipv6
  down ip -6 route del default dev he-ipv6

iface lo:1 inet static
  address 172.16.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 172.16.1.0

auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet manual
  bond-master bond0

auto eth1
  iface eth1 inet manual
  bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
  address 10.3.0.1
  netmask 255.0.0.0
  gateway 10.0.0.1
  bond-mode 6
  bond-miimon 100
  bond-lacp-rate 1
  bond-slaves none
```

`ethtool ethX` output:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
    Link detected: yes


Settings for eth1:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 24
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
                   drv
    Link detected: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to add:

```
bond-slaves eth0 eth1
```

to my interfaces file to get bonding to work in active-backup mode (contrary to instructions on Ubuntu docs website...)

I am now trying to get one of the more complicated (and useful) bonding modes (like balance alb) working...